# Appengine over quota

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-quotas

I'm using appengine already for a long time, but today, my application is already after 3 hours over quota (> my daily cost). The dashboard howevers show almost no resources have been used, so it should be nowhere near this daily limit.

Also strange is that, dispite the fact that the dashboard says my daily limit is reached, I noticed that I have no problem for retrieving. Only writing to the datastore gives an over quota exception  (com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$OverQuotaException: The API call datastore_v3.Put() required more quota than is available). The statistics below however show there where not a lot of writes. If I look to Quota details, all indicators are Okay.

```
Billing Status: Enabled ( Daily budget: $2.00 ) - Settings Quotas reset every 24 hours. Next reset: 21 hrs  

Resource                    Usage               Billable Price             Cost

Frontend Instance Hours     4.30 Instance Hours 0.00    $0.08/ Hour     $0.00
Backend Instance Hours      0.00 Instance Hours 0.00    $0.08/ Hour     $0.00
Datastore Stored Data       2.86 GBytes         1.86    $0.008/ GByte-day   $0.02
Logs Stored Data            0.04 GBytes         0.00    $0.008/ GByte-day   $0.00
Task Queue Stored Task Bytes0.00 GBytes         0.00    $0.008/ GByte-day   $0.00
Blobstore Stored Data       0.00 GBytes         0.00    $0.0043/ GByte-day  $0.00
Code and Static File Storage0.12 GBytes         0.00    $0.0043/ GByte-day  $0.00
Datastore Write Operations  0.06 Million Ops    0.01    $1.00/ Million Ops  $0.02
Datastore Read Operations   0.01 Million Ops    0.00    $0.70/ Million Ops  $0.00
Datastore Small Operations  0.00 Million Ops    0.00    $0.10/ Million Ops  $0.00
Outgoing Bandwidth          0.01 GBytes         0.00    $0.12/ GByte       $0.00
Recipients Emailed          0                   0       $0.01/ 100 Recipients$0.00
Stanzas Sent                0                   0       $0.10/ 100K Stanzas $0.00
Channels Created            0%  0 of 95,040     0       $0.01/ 100 Opens    $0.00
Logs Read Bandwidth         0.00 GBytes         0.00    $0.12/ GByte        $0.00
PageSpeed Outgoing Bandwidth0.01 GBytes         0.01    $0.39/ GByte        $0.01
SSL VIPs                    0                   0       $1.30/ Day          $0.00
SSL SNI Certificates        0                   0       $0.06/ Day          $0.00

Estimated cost for the last 3 hours:    $2.00* / $2.00
```

Comment: the problem solved itself after a couple of hours.

Comment: if it happens again, the bug is at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8525

Comment: and the issues page is not available to public access.